# What is the best way to avoid redundancy with these tables

Tags: database-normalization

I am trying to make a database with a plan table.|
The plans are: Basic, Express, Advanced, and Professional
Each of them will have a pricetag and support plans like PHP, ASP and SSL support.

```
        Basic:      Express
price - 69,00       89,00    
setup - 0,00         0,00
SSL -    X           Yes
PHP -    X           Yes
ASP -    X            X
```

How am I able to make an ERD without causing redundancy.

I thought about making a table like:

```
    Table Plans:
    ID     Pname     Pprice     Psetup     Pasp     Pphp     Pssl
    0      Basic     69,00      0,00       0        0        0
    1      Express   89,00      0,00       0        1        1
    etc..
```

The plans will be expanded with more types. But eventually that will make the table too large so I thought about creating another table.

```
    Table Plans:
    ID     Pname     Pprice     Psetup     Plansbool
    0      Basic     69,00      0,00       0
    1      Express   89,00      0,00       1


    Table Plansbool:
    ID     Bname     YesNo      PlansID
    0      Php       0          0
    1      Php       1          1
    2      Asp       0          0
    3      Asp       0          1
    4      Ssl       0          0 
    5      Ssl       1          1
```

But this also creates the problem that in the table "plans", the plans can only accept one of the types in the Plansbool table.. I also think this is redundant and right now I can't see the big picture of creating a non redundant plan table with the according types of support..

I'm sorry if this is really easily solved or to confusing.

Comment: You have plans and prices. You have features available to plans. I don't see the issue.

Comment: The problem is that for example, basic will not have PHP support and advanced will have PHP support. I wanted to create a table for the support types that have a bool column, a 0 for no support and a 1 for support. 

The problem is that I want to avoid redundancy by as an example not have PHP show itself 4 times in the table just because it might have different bools.

Comment: But you have four different values. I mean, you could have a join table with the feature id, plan id, and value, but that's about the only "optimization". You're over-thinking what is essentially zero data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your idea how to solve this is no redundancy.
Redundancy would be created when you are able to find the same data by using two different ways.

I am confused by what "plans" are. Are plans Basic, Express and so on, or are plans PHP, ASP... ?

I think you meant that PHP, ASP and so on are types (because in the first sentence you called them both plans (Basic, Express, ... and PHP, ASP, ...)

But make a table with the plans (Basic, Express, ...) and so on and another table with the types (PHP, ASP, ...)

Than make a many to many - connection and just resolve it with the attribut "Price" and "Stetup".
[image]

And the columns:

```
Plan (PlanID, Name)
PlanType (PlanID, TypeID, Price, Setup)
Type (TypeID, Name)
```

And just add a "PlanType" when there is a plan for a type :-)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The plans are the basic, express, advanced and professional. Each of these plans have support or no support for SSL, ASP, or PHP.

But will I be able to give different bools to the PHP, ASP table ? Because basic will not have PHP or ASP support, but for example advanced will.

Comment: @RickJellema Everything which is stored in the PlanType-Table for that exists a support. If it's not in the PlanType-Table, than there is no support.

Comment: So, the PlanType-Table maps the plan and the type together. If Basic and PHP are not mapped together, than Basic doesn't support PHP.

Comment: I think I get it now. So when Basic is in the PlanType-table mapped with the setup and price, but there is no foreign-key for the type, it has no support. 
I feel kind of stupid right now though, but thanks for helping me!

Comment: @RickJellema haha :D 
But to explain what I mean: When you want to save in the database that Advanced supports PHP, than you create a PlanType-Entry were Advanced and PHP are mapped together. When you want to save in the database that Basic doesn't support PHP, than you just don't make a PlanType-Entry.

In the PlanType-Table are just those types mapped to plans, which are also supported by those. 

So if you want to know if a plan supports a type, you just look up "PlanType" with the planID and the TypeID. If there isn't any entry for those two, than this plan doesn't support this type.

Comment: @RickJellema if something isn't clear - feel free to ask :-)

Comment: actually it's very clear, the answer was really sitting infront of my face hahaha, I've been using it in similair issue's I had with normalizing plans and types.

Thanks for the help :)!